# Carregar Valor no Input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Bom Dia,

Estou tentando carregar um valor no Input depois que o usuário clica no botão.

```
// Este é o Botão
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1" onclick="id_host()"> Identificar Nome </button>
```

Quando ele clicar neste botão, quero que ele vá para uma pagina `.php` e faça um `gethostname()`  e retorne com o resultado, atribuindo no input.

Segue o código para melhor entendimento:

```
// Função quando Clicar no Botão.
    function id_host() {                    
    var n_pc = $("#conteudo").load("processa.php");
    document.getElementById('#conteudo').value = n_pc;
    }
```

Este é o Input que quero popular com o resultado de `processa.php`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="conteudo" id="conteudo" value="">
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Grato.

Comment: O `load` vai carregar o resultado do `processa.php` pra dentro do elemento com id 'conteudo'. Então o deveria fazer `var n_pc = $("#conteudo").text();`

Comment: Não entendi, no caso ficaria assim: `$("#conteudo").load("processa.php");` e `var n_pc = $("#conteudo").text();` ??

Comment: Isso mesmo. O `load` não retorna nada, ele apenas 'joga' o conteúdo no elemento 'conteudo'.

Comment: Cara, não deu certo! =/

Comment: O que o seu `processa.php` retorna, um texto puro, um html, um json ou oque?

Answer (score 2):

A função **load** é para carregar um conteúdo (geralmente algum HTML), dentro de um determinado elemento, ou seja, no seu caso `$("#conteudo").load("processa.php");` você está carregando o conteúdo de `processa.php` dentro do elemento `$("#conteudo")`.

Utilize a função **ajax** em vez de **load**, e também faça com que o resultado seja colocado no *callback* da função. Também recomendo realizar o retorno com formato **`json`**.

### Exemplo

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'processa.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
      $('#conteudo').val(data.texto);
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
   }
});
```

**processa.php**

```
<?php
   echo json_encode(Array('texto' => 'texto de exemplo'));
```

### Explicando

A parte

```
   success: function(data){
      $('#conteudo').val(data.texto);
   }
```

será executada quando o `ajax` receber o retorno do `processa.php`, e esse retorno virá no parâmetro `data`. A propriedade `texto` do parâmetro `data`, foi definido lá no `processa.php`, codificando para o formato `json` pela função `json_encode`.

Caso o script `processa.php` tenha algum erro, e não é executado corretamente, então a função `success: function(data){ ... }` não será executada, em vez disso será executada a função `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... }`, e os parâmetros serão objetos contendo as informações do erro, nela você pode colocar um `alert` informando ao usuário que a consulta não pode ser completada, ficando assim:

```
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      alert('Não foi possível completar a requisição.');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Tente usar o método `.val()`

```
// Função quando Clicar no Botão.
    function id_host() {                    
    var n_pc = $("#conteudo").load("processa.php");

     //Use o método VAL do jquery
    $("#conteudo").val(n_pc);
    }
```

Se não funcionar, tente adicionar um `return` no botão.

```
// Este é o Botão
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1" onclick="return id_host();"> Identificar Nome </button>
```